# PROCEDURE Warning: execution completed with warning

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I'm having a problem with this procedure. The error I keep receiving is:

```
dbms_warning.set_warning_setting_string 'ENABLE:ALL', succeeded.
PROCEDURE promo_ship_sp compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
```

I have tried setting error reporting on so I would get a little bit more information, but nothing else shows up. `SELECT * FROM BB_PROMOLIST;` shows results in 0 rows fetched so it can't be an insert id issue can it? I have commited it, and it still fails to compile successfully.

```
set serveroutput on;
CALL DBMS_WARNING.set_warning_setting_string ('ENABLE:ALL', 'SESSION');
create or replace procedure promo_ship_sp  
  (
    tmp_id in date
  )
IS
v_dt date := tmp_id;
v_Promo_flag bb_promolist.promo_flag%type;
cursor cur_select is
    select idshopper, dtcreated
    from bb_basket 
  where dtcreated < v_dt
  order by idshopper;

BEGIN
 for rec_something in cur_select loop   
     insert into bb_promolist (idshopper, month, year, promo_flag, used) values
     (rec_something.idshopper, 'JAN', '2010', 1, 'N');
     dbms_output.put_line(rec_something.idshopper  || ' ' ||rec_something.dtcreated);
 end loop;
END;
/ 
show errors;
execute promo_ship_sp('15-FEB-07');
```

---

GOOD Catch on the stack overflow, but that wasn't it on my actual code. I disabled the constraints and then compiled without warnings and then enabled the constraints again and can execute it as many times as I please. Kinda wierd bug. Hope this helps someone.

```
set serveroutput on;
CALL DBMS_WARNING.set_warning_setting_string ('ENABLE:ALL', 'SESSION');
create or replace procedure promo_ship_sp  
  (
    tmp_id in date
  )
IS
v_dt date := tmp_id;
v_Promo_flag bb_promolist.promo_flag%type;
cursor cur_select is
    select idshopper, dtcreated
    from bb_basket 
  where dtcreated < v_dt
  order by idshopper;

BEGIN
 delete from bb_promolist;
 for rec_something in cur_select loop   
     insert into bb_promolist (idshopper, month, year, promo_flag, used) values
     (rec_something.idshopper, to_char(rec_something.dtcreated, 'MON'),  to_char(rec_something.dtcreated, 'YYYY'), 1, 'N');
 end loop;
END;
/ 
show errors;
execute promo_ship_sp('15-FEB-07');
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting on SO has shown you the problem. You're missing a `'` around `'Jan`. There's no need to `commit` a package.

Comment: If you compile again with the constraints enabled, the error occurs?

Comment: What client are you using to compile the procedure?

Comment: Without table definitions it is hard to know, but the warning might be: `PLW-07202: bind type would result in conversion away from column type` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/plwus.htm#sthref14004

Comment: And `v_dt date := tmp_id;` should not even compile, there is no type declared. (Unless things have changed since 10g.)

Comment: @shannon, that's how I read it initially as well, but it's declared as a date

Comment: @Ben: Doh! I totally did not see the type specified after `v_dt` and `:=...`. That is totally legal.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but too long for a comment.

Please replace the cursor, the cursor for loop and the `insert ... values` with:

```
  insert into bb_promolist (idshopper, month, year, promo_flag, used)
  select idshopper, to_char(dtcreated, 'MON'),  to_char(dtcreated, 'YYYY'), 1, 'N'
    from bb_basket 
  where dtcreated < v_dt;
```

Include the order by clause only if you have a good reason, such as putting data with the same values on the same block:

```
  insert into bb_promolist (idshopper, month, year, promo_flag, used)
  select idshopper, to_char(dtcreated, 'MON'),  to_char(dtcreated, 'YYYY'), 1, 'N'
    from bb_basket 
  where dtcreated < v_dt
  order by idshopper;
```